# i can't stop setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have two `buttons`. The one `onClick` runs a function that uses a `var intId = setInterval{function(), 30}`
On the second `button` i try to stop the setInterval with `clearInterval(intId)` but `intId` is not global virable and if i put the whole setInterval outside of the function of the button it can't run.

> run button

```
var intID == 0;

function runButton() {
  var c = document.getElementById("can1");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  var speed = 2;
  var posX = 20;
  var posY = 20;

  var intID = setInterval(function() {
    posX += speed;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, 20, 20);

    if (intID == 1) {
        clearInterval(intID);
        }
  }
      , 30);

}
```

> stop button

```
function stopButton() {
  var c = document.getElementById("can1");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


  clearInterval(intID);
  intID == 1;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  c.style.backgroundColor = red;
}
```

Comment: `intID` is not in scope inside `stopButton`. Declare it outside both functions instead.

Comment: `intervalID = 0`  ==> `intervalID == 0`

Comment: I tried that as well but now `runButton()` is not even working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/TsigkrosNikos/pen/PQrgbQ)

Comment: `var intID == 0;` and `var intID = setInterval(function() {` are two seperate variables in two seperate contexts that just happen to have the same name. Guess wich one is used by `clearInterval(intID);`?

Comment: Still i can't figure out the solution yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows.

```
var intervalID = 1;

function runButton() {
  var c = document.getElementById("can1");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  var speed = 2;
  var posX = 20;
  var posY = 20;

  var intID = setInterval(function() {
    posX += speed; //variable 'x' had to change to 'posX'
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, 20, 20);

    if(intervalID == 0) {
        clearInterval(intID);
    }
  }, 30);
}

function stopButton() {
  var c = document.getElementById("can1");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  intervalID = 0;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  c.style.backgroundColor = red;
}
```

Comment: I see the logic of placing a new global `var intervalID` but it doesn't work either and i can't understand why. [code here](https://codepen.io/TsigkrosNikos/pen/LmojNV)

Comment: @NickTsigkros, I have got two errors in pen. `x` is not defined and `red` is not defined. Please declare x and put red in quotes.

Comment: Yes i just found the same thing because i copied the whole code from here! Now it works perfect now thank you!!!